# How to define a global func pointer and assign to a specific address

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, function-pointers

This should be obvious to experienced C programmers, but not to me.
My situation: I have a constant address of a function. I want to define a symbol, assign to the address and be able to call it like a function. I want this function to be in a separate header file, so I can include it anywhere I need the function.

What I've done so far:

```
// utils.h
#pragma once

typedef int* (*funptr)();
const funptr get_game_obj2 = (funptr2)0x00401870;
```

This code works as expected. But. I'm trying to find out how to achieve the same without typedef. 
I tried different combinations of the type and parentheses, but nothing works. I have a strong feeling that it should be doable, but cannot find any reference to google it right.

```
 const int* (*get_game_obj2)() = (int* (*)())0x00401870;
 (int* (*)()) get_game_obj2 = (int* (*)())0x00401870;
 int* (*)() get_game_obj2 = (int* (*)())0x00401870;
 const( int* (*get_game_obj2)()) = 0x00401870;
```

BTW, previously I ran into a problem that working code compiled twice and i was getting redefinition compilation error.
`fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`
I think this happened because I include the header file from multiple source files. I managed that with `const` keyword. But what bothers me is the fact, that before `const` I tried `#pragma once` and an include guard like this:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GRANDPARENT_H
#define GRANDPARENT_H
  typedef int* (*funptr)();
  funptr get_game_obj2 = (funptr2)0x00401870;
#endif /* !GRANDPARENT_H */
```

And my expectation is that with such a guard this file should only be executed once during compilation, so no redefinitions should happen. Why didn't this work, but `const` did? 
Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with function pointers.  If that type were a simple `int`, you would get the same issue of the multiple definitions.  Enter the `extern` keyword.

Comment: 1. your scenario seems a bit weird to me, are you sure you have a fixed address in which your function sits ? this seems very breakable to me.

2. why would you want to avoid a typedef, it seems like the best option for your case, most readable by far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close.

`const` on a typedef applies to its toplevel type, for `int *(*)()` that's the pointer-to-function, so `const funptr` gets you `int *(*const)()`, a constant-pointer-to-function.

```
int *(*const get_game_obj2)() = (int *(*)())0x401870;
```

edit:

> I include the header file from multiple source files. I managed that with const keyword. But what bothers me is the fact, that before const I tried #pragma once and an include guard

Source files are compiled separately, if you define objects in a header, include that header in multiple source files, and compile them all, you get definitions of those objects in each compiled file. Trying to link those together will get you a multiple-definitions error from just about any linker.

For something as simple as a constant like this you could probably get away with

```
#define get_game_obj2 ((int *(*)())0x401870)
```

simply declaring the conversion inline.

This kind of code's fun as a learning device and useful if you're writing microcontroller code where every bit is precious, but the effort and complexity and fragility are real expenses.  You're not accountable to SO for them, but whoever you are accountable to for this code should have concrete, not abstract, not handwavy, concrete, justification for doing it this way.  As in "if we don't do it this way we risk the code not fitting in the eeprom" or "if we don't do it  this way you never wrap your head around C type syntax".

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and more important, now I have a better understanding of what's going on in this code. I still don't really understand why `const` solved the issue, but in order to acomplish it without const I could declare my variable in header file with modifier `extern` and define(assign to the address) in a separate source file.

But in any variation of this approach I would end up having a variable containing an address of the function. And using this variable as a function pointer I could use the function. Right?

Comment: What I like about `#define` approach is that I don't even store that address anywhere, I just use that address in-place with a type-check done by C compiler. That was my initial vision how I want to do it.
I'm not greedy about another 4 bytes, but it's meaningless. I think that's the way to go in my situation.

Comment: How linkers treat multiple identical definitions of a `const` object is a bit arbitrary, I no longer remember whether C requires a diagnostic or perhaps even allows for that.

Comment: … but C++ _does_ allow for it, by bypassing the arbitrariness entirely.  const object definitions not explicitly marked extern don't have global linkage at all, the definition is local to the defining file.  But you were asking about C, which a little digging reminded me treats them as externs and doesn't mark for any sort of linker coalescing.

Comment: … so with a C++ compiler you'd end up with a file-scope const variable containing the function address but the compiler would very likely fold it in as a literal, because C++ is built around eliminating abstraction penalties like this.  A C compiler will have a global-scope variable with the function address and I forget whether it's allowed to presume the `const` is honored everywhere, that seems iffy to me.